# Problem in Pairing the Android device with other Device through Bluetooth

Tags: android

I have a problem in pairing the android Device (Desire) with any other Device (e.g Nokia) through Bluetooth, and i am using the Application the (Bluetooth-Chat) provided in the samples of the SDK 2.2, the behavior of the Application is that it shows all the devices having bluetooth switched on, and also paired it but only android devices, so how can i connect the android device with any other device (e.g Nokia), what are the limitations, what needs to be change in the Code, i tried to debug the Code and find out where the problem exists but i do not found any reason. 
So kindly help me in this regard, i will be very thankful to you.